# Combine - test if CurrentValueSubject has any subscribers

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I would like to verify if some `CurrentValueSubject` has any subscriptions added. Is there any way to verify this?

Comment: Subscriptions or subscribers? There is a big difference. And why would you need to know this? Seems to violate the whole purpose of Combine.

Comment: You might find also helpful proposed approach in [Swift Combine: Check if Subject has observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364345/swift-combine-check-if-subject-has-observer/59127673?r=SearchResults&s=4|0.0000#59127673) topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way maybe is to use `handleEvents` and keep track with a counter.

```
class A {

    var count = 0
    let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(true)

    func myStuff() {
        subject.handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [unowned self] _ in
            self.count += 1
        }, receiveCompletion: { [unowned self] _ in
            self.count -= 1
        }, receiveCancel: {
            self.count -= 1
        })
    }
}
```

Not sure if this can fit your problem though.

You could even create a custom `Publisher` that internally handles the count and exposes it as a read only property, which maybe it's better.