# Timeout on shared() operator

Tags: swift, combine

In the following code sub1 and sub2 subscribe to the shared increment publisher one after another and then both cancel. Later sub3 subscribes to the publisher but it now receives no values at all. How could I add a timeout so that sub3 will receive values so long as it subscribes before the timeout expires?

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let everySecPublisher = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1.0, runLoop: .main, mode: .default).autoconnect()
let incrementPublisher = everySecPublisher.scan(0, {x, _ in x + 1})
let shared = incrementPublisher.share()


let sub1 = shared.sink(receiveValue: { value in print("1:\(value)") })
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2))


let sub2 = shared.sink(receiveValue: {value in print("2:\(value)") })
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2))


sub1.cancel()
sub2.cancel()
let sub3 = shared.sink(receiveValue: {value in print("3:\(value)") })
RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 2))

print("finished")
```

output

```
1:1
1:2
1:3
2:3
1:4
2:4
finished
```

Comment: A canceled pipeline is dead. Its publisher will never publish again.

Comment: If there's a subject in the pipeline then it's possible to control when it cancels it's own subscription to an upstream publisher (after a timeout in this case). I was hoping there would be some mechanism built into Combine to facilitate this but it looks like I'll need to build it from scratch.

Comment: I don't see how what you're describing would be Combine at all. This might be an x-y question. It would be better to describe what you are really trying to do as a genuine use case.

Comment: I'm using RxBluetoothKit to get connections to bluetooth peripherals. If two views in my UI make use of the same peripheral I want them to share this connection rather than have to establish a new connection. As each connection is bound to an RxSwift subscription I need to share that subscription between multiple upstream subscribers (the rest of my app uses Combine so I convert the RxSwift subscriptions to Combine subscriptions using https://github.com/CombineCommunity/RxCombine).

Comment: In addition to sharing these connections I also want to keep the connections alive for a period of time after all subscriptions have cancelled so that the bluetooth connection doesn't need to be re-established.

Comment: Hmm, well you can certainly write a simple operator that doesn't pass a `cancel` call up the stream. So maybe that's the answer after all.

Comment: Yes it does appear that a custom operator is the way to go, I've found some useful information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364345/swift-combine-check-if-subject-has-observer

Comment: I have a template here that gets you started: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorscustom.html

Comment: @matt that's nicely written, many thanks!

Comment: You can also look at Apple's implementation of [`Timer.TimerPublisher`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BTimer.swift) for guidance. Apple's code is thread-safe.